# checking the status of CPU throttling: whether ON or OFF

Tags: cpu, throttling

I am trying to install the ATLAS BLAS library which recommends that I turn if CPU throttling to do the install.

How do I check if my CPU throttling is ON or OFF?

I tried the suggestion of
Code:

```
./cpufreq-selector -g performance
```

in the /usr/bin directory as suggested elsewhere in the forum but there was no output and the control returned back to the user.

I have searched everywhere but there does not seem to be a way to determine the status of the CPU throttling

Answer (score -1):

The throttling control is managed by the *cpuspeed daemon* on RedHat 5\6

You can stop the daemon:

```
service cpuspeed stop
```

More information can be found on the [cpuspeed daemon man](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cpuspeed).